# How to parse the json response returned from the HttpBuilder in Groovy?

Tags: json, groovy

The following is what GitHub returns from a REST GET method. How to parse it using JSON?

```
response.success = { resp, reader ->
            result = reader.text
        }

[{"login":"ghost","id":1,"avatar_url": ....},{"login":"github-enterprise","id":2,"avatar_url": ....}]
```

Comment: Use RestBuilder and it parses it for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use awesome tool for working with json - `json slurper`:

```
    def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
    def result = slurper.parseText(result)
    def firstLogin = result[0].login
    def secondId = result[1].id
```